# warning.js:45 Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `.1:$..`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm receiving a ton of these errors, one after the other with different keys attached to the warning message. Is there a way to find out where they are coming from based on the id key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually a pain to find out where you've made the key mistake, and in React 15, `data-reactid` is never even rendered to the DOM, making it harder. In normal versions, just inspect the DOM and start looking for elements that have `data-reactid=.1:$....`.

Anyway, the error comes from setting the `key` prop manually somewhere, so start looking for that in your components. This is usually an issue if you have an array, and render components for each value of this array:

```
var things = [1,2,3,4].map(function(value, index){
  // This will cause Warning: flattenChildren... because
  // every div will be given the same React ID
  return (
    <div key="FIXED_KEY">{value}</div>
  );
})
```

Now, in a case like this, you *have* to set the key manually, just make sure that the key is unique for each rendered component in the same loop.